# Entity Framework 6.4 - many to many relation returns new empty List instead of data

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

So I'm certain this is a stupid error that I've overlooked, but I can't find it.
I'm trying to map a many-to-many relationship with Entity Framework, but while everything is working successfully in the initializer, the `Role` attributes only return a new empty list without loading data from the database.

If I put a breakpoint the code at the `DataInitializer`, then everything works, the `ApplicationUser` has the `Roles` and the roles know the `ApplicationUser`.

When verifying in the database itself, all the data is correct and present how it is supposed to be. However when I continue the code and arrive at a controller, then no (User)Roles are present in the `ApplicationUser`, but no `UserRoles` are present in the `Roles` neither.

I have a `Role`, `UserRole` and `ApplicationUser` and the many-to-many relationship is mapped in my `UserRoleConfiguration`.

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<ApplicationUser> _users;

    public UserRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _users = context.ApplicationUser;
    }

    public ApplicationUser GetByMailAndPassword(string email, string password)
    {
        return _users.Include(i => i.Role).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email && u.Password == password);
    }

    public ApplicationUser GetByUsernameAndPassword(string username, string password)
    {
        return _users.Include(i => i.Role).FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username && u.Password == password);
    }

    public void NewUser(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        _users.Add(user);
    }

    public void SaveChanges() 
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Role**

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public RoleEnums RoleEnum {get; set;}
    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    public Role(RoleEnums role)
    {
        RoleEnum = role;
        UserRoles = new List<UserRole>();
    }
}

public enum RoleEnums
{
    User,
    Responsable,
    Mainresponsable
}
```

**UserRole**

```
public class UserRole 
{
    public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }

    protected UserRole()
    {
    }

    public UserRole(ApplicationUser user, Role role) : this()
    {
        User = user;
        ApplicationUserId = User.Id;
        Role = role;
        RoleId = Role.Id;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUser**

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    #region Properties
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserRole> Role { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public ApplicationUser() 
    {
        Role = new HashSet<UserRole>();
    }

    public bool ContainsRole(RoleEnums role)
    {
        return Role.Any(r => r.Role.RoleEnum == role);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**UserRoleConfiguration**

```
public class UserRoleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserRole>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserRole> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("UserRoles");
        builder.HasKey(k => new { k.RoleId, k.ApplicationUserId });
        builder.HasOne(k => k.Role).WithMany(k => k.UserRoles).HasForeignKey(k => k.RoleId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder.HasOne(k => k.User).WithMany(k => k.Role).HasForeignKey(k => k.ApplicationUserId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

**UserConfiguration**

```
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("User");
        builder.HasKey(u => u.Id);
        builder.HasMany(u => u.Role).WithOne(u => u.User).HasForeignKey(u => u.ApplicationUserId);
    }
}
```

**RoleConfiguration**

```
public class RoleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Roles");
        builder.HasKey(r => r.Id);
        builder.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles).WithOne(e => e.Role).HasForeignKey(e => e.RoleId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the meantime, the repository was not properly configured with the include and ThenInclude.

```
    return _users.Include(i => i.Role).ThenInclude(i => i.Role)
        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email && u.Password == password);
```

A special thanks to the senior ASP.NET developer who took the effort to edit my question and format the classes in my question.